# Energy density of particle species in thermal equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, cosmology, universe, thermal-radiation

I am reading the book Kolb and Turner "The Early Universe". In the thermodynamics section they mention that the total energy density of different species in equilibrium is

$$\rho=T^4\sum_{\rm i= all~ species}\left(\frac{T_i}{T}\right)^4 \frac{g_i}{2\pi^2}\int_{x_i}^\infty du\frac{(u^2-x_i^2)^{1/2}u^2}{\exp(u-y_i)\pm 1},$$

where $\pm$ stands for fermions and bosons, $x_i=m_i/T,~ y_i=\mu_i/T$, where $m_i$ is the mass of the particle species, $\mu_i$ it the chemical potential, $T$ is the photon temperature and $T_i$ is the temperature of particle species $i$.

I understand how the expression is derived but I have a few questions regarding the assumptions that go into this equation:

- How is the photon temperature defined. I understand that today we can read it of the black body spectrum that we measure. How would we calculate the photon temperature at earlier times? Do I have to use the following relation between scale factor $a$ and effective degrees of freedom?

$$a(t)=\frac{1}{g_{*s}^{1/3}T}$$

- If I can use the previous equation to calculate the photon temperature at earlier times, I think I can only use it up to $\sim 370$ ka when the CMB was released!? How was the photon temperature defined before the CMB was released?
- I understand that in the first equation of this post we do not have to assume that the particle species are in thermal equilibrium. They can be all in thermal equilibrium and then they would all have the same temperature. However the particle species can also be non-interacting and have different temperatures. Is this view correct? If yes, how would I define a common temperature if all species are in thermal equilibrium?
- How are the temperatures $T_i$ defined? Let's consider we have a thermal plasma that consists of electrons, neutrinos and photons. Do their temperatures all agree if these three species are in thermal equilibrium? And again is an interaction of these three species required for them to be in thermal equilibrium 'with each other'?
- Photons are in thermal equilibrium before and after the time of the CMB was released, correct?

Comment: Here [pdf](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS4130/v10/undervisningsmateriale/Cosmology.pdf) is a good summary of the thermodynamics of the early universe. I hope this helps. To address at least your second point: Before release of the CMB (formation of nuclei), matter and radiation were coupled and therefore had the same temperature. At certain points, different particles *decouple* from the rest and then follow their own temperature/energy density (as given in your post).

Comment: Thanks! This helps!